# SQL Server exception: Received an invalid column length from the bcp client for colid modify_time

Tags: azure-synapse

I am getting the below error while using bcp client of SQL Server to load data into Azure SQL Data warehouse.

Exact exception:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: 107096;Received an invalid column length from the bcp client for colid modify_time.

I am able to load the data correctly to Azure SQL database. But while loading the data to Azure SQL data warehouse, this issue happens.

And, this is happening only for timestamp columns.

When I created the table in Azure SQL data warehouse, it was created like this:

```
name        | type       | warehouse type | precision | length | java sql type
------------+------------+----------------+-----------+--------+-----------
modify_time | datetime2  |      -9        |   27      |   54   |  -9*
```

Bulk load operation is done by the following sample code:

```
SQLServerBulkCopy copy = new SQLServerBulkCopy(conn);

copy.setDestinationTableName("my_table");

copy.writeToServer(new ISQLServerBulkRecord() {
                 //Overridden methods
               });
```

Comment: Can you add an example timestamp you are trying to load?

Comment: Example timestamp: "2017-11-10 11:50:50.082". 
All timestamps are in these format.

Comment: This is happening for "date" type columns also. I am trying to load "2017-01-01" into a date column through bcp client.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Still didn't manage to find a solution. To me it happens only with datetime2 with precision 19.